# How to run selenium tests in jenkins?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, python-3.4

I have selenium tests written in python 3.4. How to run them from jenkins after success build ?
Process is :
1. pull from git repository
2. python setup.py build
3. python setup.py install

After that i need to run server and selenium tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to run them from jenkins after success build ? 
- You can add a trigger to your selenium job so it runs after the build job runs successfully

To answer your question accurately, I need to know whether you are planning in running selenium tests in jenkins box...

Assuming you aren't planning in running the tests in jenkins (which IMO is something you dont want to) you can take 2 different directions:

1:. add a "execute shell" step to your build with the ssh to the machine you want to fire your tests on along with the command you need to run your tests in that machine. This would mean your pull from git to get latest code from selenium would have to happen in this step

2:. if you are outsourcing your browser execution to browserstack, sauce labs etc, add a "execute shell" step with the command needed to trigger your tests (firing from jenkins). This is assuming your tests know that it should point to outsourced env etc... You will most likely have a step to start a tunnel between your CI box and outsourced env...

Comment: This is Mukul from BrowserStack. We have recently released a [Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BrowserStack+Plugin) that makes integrating your Jenkins CI with BrowserStack even easier. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Selenium](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) and [Seleniumhq](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin) plugins for the same.

To add plugin : *Manage Jenkins/ Manage Plugins/Available*